# Is this considered a semi-interactive puzzle?

Tags: discussion

It says on the tag wiki for [semi-interactive-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semi-interactive-puzzle):

> DO NOT POST PUZZLES OF THIS TYPE. This tag is kept for historical reasons, and semi-interactive puzzles should not be considered good questions for this site. **Semi-interactive puzzles are those where new parts are added to the puzzle as each part is solved.**

My instructions for my puzzle are:

> Comment and pick from the following tiny images and I will reveal a higher-res image, with details that may or may not help you solve the puzzle. I'll only be providing one reveal every day, and I'm also only revealing $\frac56$ of the tiny images.

I'm not updating the puzzle as things are solved, rather than as time goes on.

Would this be considered a [semi-interactive-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semi-interactive-puzzle)?

Comment: I don't think you need the tag. Just refer to them as clues or something.

Comment: @Areeb They are essential to solving the puzzle.

Comment: Then that would be a semi-interactive puzzle, which according to Deusovi, is forbidden. But your comment on the answer below seems to clear that up.

Comment: To be clear: the _reason_ it counts as semi-interactive is because in order to solve the puzzle it requires people to ask something of you, and for you to respond and update accordingly. _That's_ what makes it off topic. Questions are static (edits change them from one static state to another), and that's what breaks.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it would be. This type of puzzle is NOT allowed. Puzzles should be solvable from the time they are posted; edits should not be necessary except to fix errors.

Comment: I'll be revealing one clue since the puzzle start. That one clue can solve the puzzle alone.

Comment: @Peanut: What's the point of the other images then? This sounds dangerously close to "semi-interactive".

Comment: Additional verification.